# JAVA garbage collection side effects - blocking?

Tags: c#, java, garbage-collection

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [garbage collection Operation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/483427/garbage-collection-operation)

I have several questions related.

1.When JAVA garbage collector is running, does it take a lot of CPU resources?
2.What triggers a garbage collection, if i never manually do GC.collect()
3.If I monitor memory usage will I see a sudden drop of physical memory usage?
4.Is it true that collector will block other threads. e.g. GUI
5.How to avoid that.
6.This is a problem in C# too?

Thanks for answering.

Comment: In Java, you can tune the GC: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/gc-tuning-5-138395.html

Comment: Too many questions in one go. Please read the posts in the "related" section of this post, this has been asked a lot.

Answer (score 2):

1. When the GC is running, it is CPU bound so it consumes as much CPU as it can get until it is finished.
2. When you run out or run low on memory (depending on the GC you use)
3. You can monitor free memory and you will see a sudden jump in free memory.
4. Some collectors always block all threads. However the Concurrent collector has a some pahses which occur concurrently.
5. The best way to avoid GCs is create less object.  Create a low enough objects and you can go for a whole day without a GC.  http://vanillajava.blogspot.com/2011/06/how-to-avoid-garbage-collection.html
6. I imagine so.

Comment: Re: #2 - There are several types of GC.  Not all of them wait for you to run out of memory.  Most are scheduled are regular intervals.  Connect jconsole to your application's VM and you can see when they occur.

Comment: I don't know of any which will run if you are not consuming memory. Concurrent Mark Sweep GC using a usage threshold to decide when to start. The GC will appear to run at regular intervals if you are consistently consuming memory.

Answer (score 1):

I can't speak to Java, but seeing how you want to know about C# as well:

1. Define "a lot". No, in general it does not use a lot of CPU. In fact, garbage collection will usually wait until it thinks it can run w/o burdening the system.
2. Garbage collection runs kinda whenever it wants to. Even if you call `GC.Collect()` you can't expect GC to happen right away.
3. You'll only see a drop in memory usage if there's stuff that's collected. Only stuff that can be collected will be collected, and that really depends on your program.
4. No, it won't block other threads (I'll be checking CLR via C# in a sec to make sure).
5. N/A
6. This is the C# answer. :)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of trying to get a concise answer about a plethora of questions which can be read in two or three paragraphs, [why don't you take a look at the documentation](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/index-jsp-140228.html)?  It is more through than any answer that can be provided, and will tell you the why behind "it depends".